# How do I add all the elements in 2d array to a Hashset?

Tags: c++, arrays, set

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <set>
int main(){
    
    //storing soduko matrix from user 
    int Board[9][9];
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<9; j++){
            std::cin>>Board[i][j];
        }
    
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    
    
        
    
    }
```

Let's say I have a 9x9 2d array and the values are all user input, how would I add all the values to a Set.

Comment: What's an HashSet? Or do you mean `std::set`?

Comment: `std::unordered_set` is probably more in line with something named Hashset. [Documentation link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set). You'll want the `insert` or `emplace` methods.

Answer (score 1):

A `std::set` is not a hash set. It uses `operator<` (by default) to compare elements instead of a hashing functor. If you want a hash set, use `std::unordered_set`.

Whichever you choose, inserting values into the set could be made with nested loops:

```cpp
std::set<int> myset;
    
for(auto& inner : Board) {    // inner is a reference to the current inner array
    for(int value : inner) {  // loop over the values in the inner array
        std::cout << "Adding " << value << " to myset.\n";
        myset.insert(value);
    }
}
```